# Is it possible to force users to change password periodically in Windows 8.1 Pro and how?

Tags: windows, passwords, group-policy, event-log, security-policy

According to the one of the security requirements enforced upon our office, we must start to control / enforce  passwords are changed every now and then.

Is there a way to force users to change their passwords every specified periods of time in Windows 8.1 Pro?

Comment: Why not just implement a domain server and set a password expiration date for every 90 days.

Comment: How is this question off-topic? It describes real life situation related to advanced system features.

Comment: @Ramhound What is the domain server? Does it require another machine in the office?

Comment: @Lukasz Right below the question is a notice that explains the reason it was put on hold. If you edit the question so it's less of a product recommendation request (I think just removing the last sentence would probably do the trick), it might be reopened.

Comment: "How is this question off-topic? It describes real life situation related to advanced system features." It's off-topic because you're requesting software, which is off-topic. As the blurb state, instead of asking for software that does "X", describe your problem, what attempts you have made in solving it, and what you're getting stuck.   As @Ramhound suggests, you need to look into implementing a Windows Domain. If you don't know how to do that, I'd suggest a little studying, or hiring...

Comment: @Lukasz - You need to implement an Active Domain, this will allow you to set a password policy that users can't get around by simply changing since they no longer will be able to.

Comment: @Moses - I removed last sentence which suggested software. It was just  rhetoric question. I was unaware community here is so sensitive about such things. can the question be reopened now? I would really love to here more about possible solutions.

Comment: @techie007 "If you don't know how to do that, I'd suggest a little studying, or hiring"... Well, I may do that, but what would be the purpose of stackexhange if we were doing just that.

Comment: @Lukasz I think what techie007 means is that this is a good place to ask a specific, solvable problem, rather than learn how to implement a quite large hardware and software solution into your business. A good rule to follow is if the answer will likely take several books to explain, it probably would be better researched at the library. However, I've nominated the question for reopening since it appears specific enough. However the answer you're likely going to end up with is "basically no, not without a domain".

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through Local Users & Groups manager (which you can reach by typing `lusrmgr.msc` in start menu/search field.)

There you can set the password policy. This however, doesn't work with Home Premium, and possibly other versions.

See: 
http://resetchangewindows7password.com/make-users-accounts-passwords-automatically-expire-in-windows-7.htm

For a step-by-step tutorial.